# .net dataset how to get deleted child rows

Tags: .net, winforms, strongly-typed-dataset, datarelation

I have a strongly-typed dataset (VB.NET), using .NET Framework 2.0.  Given a `DataRow` in a parent `DataTable` and a `DataRelation`, I need to find all related rows in the child `DataTable` that have a `RowState` = `DataRowState.Deleted`.

Unfortunately for me, `DataRow.GetChildRows(DataRelation)` does not include child rows that have a `RowState` of `DataRowState.Deleted`.

Currently I'm doing a table scan of the child table to find the deleted rows that match the criteria of the relation, but my tables have become too large for that to work.  How can I get the deleted child rows with decent performance?

Comment: are we talking WinForms or ASP.Net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved this by using `GetChildRows(relation, DataRowVersion.Original)`.  Then, iterate through those rows and grab the ones with `RowState = DataRowState.Deleted`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [DataSet.GetChanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f8054fy.aspx) and pass the DataRowState.Deleted parameter. It should return a DataSet that contains all the rows marked as deleted.

Comment: helpful info (I upvoted), but I have a large dataset (lots of tables) and am only interested in one specific table.  table.getchanges would probably work, except I don't want a copy of the table - I want the actual datarows, since I'm performing an Update on them.